# why does my select function not working? its returning -1 and error code is 10038

Tags: c++, select, networking, client-server, winsock

my select function is returning -1 in my server code and on checking error code its returning 10038 which has this description in documentation:-
WSAENOTSOCK
10038
Socket operation on nonsocket.
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

My code:

```
nRet = select(nSocket + 1, &fr, &fw, &fe, &tv);
if (nRet > 0)
{
    //someone connects or communicates with a message over a dedicated connection
    std::cout << "data on port\n";
    ProcessRequest();
}
else
{
    if (nRet == 0)
    {
        //No connection or any communication made or you can say that none of the descriptors
        //are ready
        std::cout << "nothing on port:" << PORT << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        //it failed to connect
        std::cout << "it failed" << nRet << "\n";
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "error: " << error << "\n";
                
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

just for clearing socket(),setsockopt(),bind() and listen() calls were successful as they returned 1

Comment: Did you initialize your `fd_set`s properly?

Comment: Yes, I even checked them if they are set by FD_ISSET()

Comment: Actually I followed a tutorial and it worked at first but code was messy so I just made a class and put every function in that class and now it's not working

Comment: I guess you might want to provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)